# Time complexity will two O(n^2) algorithms take the same amount of time?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

I am having trouble fully understanding this question:

Two O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithms will always take the same amount of time for a given vale of n. True or false? Explain.

I think the answer is false, because from my understanding, I think that the asymptotic time complexity only measures the two algorithms running at  O(n<sup>2</sup>) time, however one algorithm might take longer as perhaps it might have additional O(n) components to the algorithm. Like O(n<sup>2</sup>) vs (O(n<sup>2</sup>) + O(n)).

I am not sure if my logic is correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In addition to lower order terms, big O() ignores constant factors.  Algorithms with run times of 1000n and .001n are both O(n), but for a given n, the first is a million times slower than the second. There are lots of algorithms that are asymptotically faster than the ones that are commonly used to solve the same problem. The reason for this situation is almost always a large constant factor in the run time of the asymptotically "fast"one.

Comment: This question tends to be better for [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/), though historically it would be very appropriate for Stack Overflow here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is correct but the explanation is lacking.

For one, the big O notation allows arbitrary constant factors. so both n<sup>2</sup> and 100*n<sup>2</sup> are in O(n<sup>2</sup>) but clearly the second is always larger.

Another reason is that the notation only gives an upper bound so even a runtime of n is in O(n<sup>2</sup>) so one of the algorithms may in fact be linear.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are right. Big Oh notation depicts the upper bound of time complexity. There might some extra constant term `c` or smaller term of `n` like `O(n)` added to it which won't be considered for time complexity.

Moreover,

```
for i = 0 to n
    for j = 0 to n
        // some constant time operation
    end
end
```

And

```
for i = 0 to n
    for j = i to n
        // some constant time operation
    end
end
```

Both of these are `O(n^2)` asymptotically but won't take same time.

The concept of big Oh analysis is not to calculate the precise amount of time a program takes to execute, it's not about counting how many times a loop iterates. Rather it indicates the algorithm's *growth rate* with `n`.